# Javascript - find when scrolled to the end of the page - firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have a div that contains a few pictures, using javascript i scroll left and right in that div, my problem is that for some reason in firefox the values are different that in chrome (works fine):

```js
function scroll_right() {
  document.getElementById('left').style.opacity = '1';
  document.getElementById('left').style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=100)';
  document.getElementById('scroller').scrollLeft += PixelPerInterval;
  if (!stop) t = setTimeout('scroll_right()', 10);
  else stop = false;
  scrX = document.getElementById('scroller').scrollLeft;
  pwidth = document.getElementById('cont').clientWidth;
  awidth = document.getElementById('cont').scrollWidth;
  //document.getElementById('type').innerHTML = scrX + ' ' + (awidth-pwidth);
  if (scrX >= awidth - pwidth) {
    //type.innerHTML = scrX + ' right';
    document.getElementById('right').style.opacity = '0.4';
    document.getElementById('right').style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=40)';
  }
}
```

using scroll_left it's easy, just have scrX = 0.
The outer container is called scroller its width is fixed, and the inner container is called cont and its width isn't set by the user so unlimited pictures can be entered.

Any ideas? (without using jquery).

thanks alot.

Btw html code:

```html
<img src="left.png" id="left" onmouseover="scroll_left();" onmouseout="stop_scroll();" />
<div id="scroller">
  <div id="cont">
    <a onclick="main(this);" href="#">
      <img class="thumb" id="persp" src="sport/911-persp.png" alt="persp" />
    </a>
    <a onclick="main(this);" href="#">
      <img class="thumb" id="side" src="sport/911-side.png" alt="side" />
    </a>
    <a onclick="main(this);" href="#">
      <img class="thumb" id="front" src="sport/911-front.png" alt="front" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<img src="right.png" id="right" onmouseover="scroll_right();" onmouseout="stop_scroll();" />
```

Comment: There is alot of data missing - `PixelPerInterval`, `scroll_right`, `stop_scroll`...

Comment: PixelPerInterval is just a value set to 1pixel atm, scroll_right is the problematic while scroll left is exactly the same just using .scrollLeft-=PixelPerInterval; and stop_scroll just sets "stop" to be true and then it doesn't call itself again (scroll_left/right).